# Help solving the quadratic equation $ax^2-4bx+4bc-\frac{d^2}{a}=0$

Tags: soft-question, diophantine-equations, quadratics

I have been struggling to solve this quadratic equation in the variable $x$ with integral coefficients: $$ax^2-4bx+4bc-\frac{d^2}{a}=0$$ 
$a\neq 0$ of course.How do I ensure that $x$ is an integer?

What I have done:

$$\Delta^2=(-4b)^2-4a(4bc-\frac{d^2}{a})$$

$$\Delta^2=16b^2-16abc+4d^2$$

I know that $d^2\equiv 0\pmod a$. So there exists a non-zero $k$ such that $d^2=ak$

$$\Delta^2=16b^2-16abc+4(ak)^2$$

$$(\dfrac{\Delta}{2})^2=(2b)^2-2(2b)ac+(ak)^2$$
Can I conclude that $c=\pm k$? How do I proceed from here?

Comment: To clarify, you want a condition that ensures $x$ is an integer?

Comment: that is correct.

Comment: I know this condition works, $ b \equiv 0\pmod a$ , $d \equiv 0\pmod a$, $b=ac$.

Comment: it's easy to find a condition that works. I need to find all of them.

Comment: Oh ok, you want an if and only if condition, or just all possible conditions